# Django ListView filter and orderby with pagination

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a simple e-commerce website. I'm using ListView to represent home page of website that displays items. I want to be able to filter Items by their category and be able to order by some factor (for example price). By default it should show all items. And if there is another page of items of given kind it should keep filter. Question is how do I connect filter function with anchor tags in my home-page.html and make it work with multiple pages of filtered items?

My code.

views.py:

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView,
from .models import ShopItem

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = ShopItem
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = "home-page.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('filter', '')
        if not q:
            return self.model.objects.all()
        return self.model.objects.filter(category=q)
```

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models

class ShopItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

home-page.html:

```html
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/">All
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Necklace</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Earrings</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bracelets</a>
</li>

{% if is_paginated %}
<nav class="d-flex justify-content-center wow fadeIn">
  <ul class="pagination pg-blue">

    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == page %}
        <li class="page-item active">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}
            <span class="sr-only">{{ page }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - see in question, it is not work with "multiple pages of filtered items". in template of paginator is querystring hardcoded, and, of course, it is not work with other filter in get.

Answer (score 0):

of course it is not work. In your template you have hard-coded page links without filter.

```
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}">
      <-- href should be something like "?page={{ page }}&filter={{filter}}" -->
      <-- or you can get filter from request "?page={{ page }}&filter={{request.GET.filter}}" -->
        {{ page }}
        <span class="sr-only">{{ page }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

And, of course, don't forget to add 'filter' in context, if you use variable.

Comment: That would result in unfiltered pages having 'filter=' in url which even though don't change anything, I'm still trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <!-- pagination from django-->
      {% if is_paginated %}
      <nav class="" aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
          <li>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm me-2">&laquo; PREV 
            </a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
          <li>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"> NEXT &raquo;
            </a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </nav>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).